# Does the convergence in probability to 1 of max to min of two samples mean the random variable divided by its mean converges to 1 in probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $\{X_n\}$ be a sequence positive real valued random variables with the first two moments (i.e. means and variances) being positive. For each $n \ge 1, $ let $X_{n1}, X_{n2}$ denote the two iid random samples generated by $X_n.$ Let $M_n, m_n$ denote the max and min of the above two random samples:

$$M_n:=max(X_{n1}, X_{n2}), m_n:= min(X_{n1}, X_{n2}).$$

Let's go to the question now.

**Motivation:** If we were to assume that $\frac{X_n}{EX_n}\to_{p}1, n \to \infty$ (converge to one in probability), then it's easy to see that $\frac{M_n}{m_n}\to_{p}1, n \to \infty.$ For completeness, here's a quick proof of that:

$ \frac{X_n}{EX_n}\to_{p}1$

$ \implies \forall \epsilon >0, lim_{n\to \infty} P[|\frac{X_n}{EX_n} -1| \le \epsilon]  = 1$

$ \implies \forall \epsilon >0, lim_{n\to \infty} P[(1-\epsilon) EX_n \le X_n \le (1+\epsilon) EX_n] = 1$

$ \implies \forall \epsilon >0, lim_{n\to \infty} P[(1-\epsilon) EX_n \le X_{n1}, X_{n2} \le (1+\epsilon) EX_n] = 1$

$\implies  \forall \epsilon >0, lim_{n\to \infty} P[(1-\epsilon) EX_n \le m_n \le M_n \le (1+\epsilon) EX_n ] =1$

$ \implies lim_{n\to \infty} P[\frac{1-\epsilon}{1+\epsilon} \le \frac{M_n}{m_n}\le \frac{1+\epsilon}{1-\epsilon} ]=1.$

Next, noting that both $\frac{1-\epsilon}{1+\epsilon},\frac{1+\epsilon}{1-\epsilon}\to 1, \text{ as } \epsilon \to 0,$ we conclude that  $\frac{M_n}{m_n}\to_{p}1.$

**Possible converse:** I don't think the converse is true, i.e. if $\frac{M_n}{m_n}\to_{p}1,$ then we may not necessarily have: $\frac{X_n}{EX_n}\to_{p}1,$ even if $EX_n > 0$ exists. I'm trying to construct such a counterexample: any hint or help appreciated. I'm thinking of starting with a usual culprit that we often use, but not sure it'll work: define $X_n=n$ with probability $1/n,$ and $X_n=0$ with probability $1-\frac{1}{n}.$ Then $EX_n=1, X_n/EX_n = X_n$ itself.

Comment: The definitions of $X_{n1}$ and $X_{n2}$ are unclear. Do you mean that $\{X_{n1}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $\{X_{n2}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ are i.i.d. copies of the sequence $\{X_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$? Even if that is what you mean, how can you directly relate $X_n$ and $m$ or $M$, the latter both defined in terms of $X_{n1}$ and $X_{n2}$? (I'm casting doubt on your "quick proof" here - specifically, the second implication stated.)

Comment: @jerkajerka Thanks a lot for your comment! Indeed, this is what I meant - $X_{n1}, X_{n2}$ were iid copies of $X_n.$ Next, yes I made a mistake in writing $\le X_n$ in the second implication "$\implies  \forall \epsilon >0, lim_{n\to \infty} P[(1-\epsilon) EX_n \le m_n \le X_n \le M_n \le (1+\epsilon) EX_n ] =1 $". It's modified now to:
$\implies  \forall \epsilon >0, lim_{n\to \infty} P[(1-\epsilon) EX_n \le m_n \le M_n \le (1+\epsilon) EX_n ] =1 .$ The rest of the question has been modified accordingly as well. Let me know if it's clear?

Comment: @jerkajerka P.S. After modification, the second implication, which you rightfully questioned, has become the **fourth** implication.

Answer (score 2):

The idea for your counterexample is good, but it doesn’t work in this form because you divide by $0$ when $m_n=0$. Just shift e.g. to $X_n=n+1$ with probability $\frac1n$ and $X_n=1$ with probability $1-\frac1n$; then $\mathsf EX_n=2$ and $\frac{X_n}{\mathsf EX_n}=\frac{X_n}2\not\to_p1$, yet $M_n=1$ with probability $\left(1-\frac1n\right)^2\to_{n\to\infty}1$ and $m_n=1$ with probability $1-\left(\frac1n\right)^2\to_{n\to\infty}1$, so $\frac{M_n}{m_n}\to_p1$.

Comment: Adding a detail to @joriki's answer: To see that $X_{n}/\mathrm{E}[X_n]$ does *not* converge to one in probability, observe that $\mathrm{P}(|X_{n}/\mathrm{E}[X_n]-1|\geqslant \epsilon)=\mathrm{P}(|X_{n}-2|\geqslant 2 \epsilon)\geqslant \mathrm{P}(X_{n}\leqslant 2(1-\epsilon))$. Picking $\epsilon=1/2$, this lower bound equals $\mathrm{P}(X_{n}=1)=1-n^{-1}$, which goes to one as $n\to\infty$---*not* zero.

Comment: @jerkajerka, joriki, Thank you for your answer and comment, sorry for this belated acknowledgement.  Just to make sure I understand correctly, I'm just checking in: I think $X_n=n^2 wp 1/n, X_n=1 wp 1-1/n$ is yet another example right? Because in this case $EX_n=n + 1-1/n \to \infty, n \to \infty,$ but $X_n \to_{p} 1.$ So $X_n/EX_n \to_{p} 0,$ but here also, just like your example, $M_n/m_n \to_{p}1.$ Is this correct?

Comment: @jerkajerka Thanks for your comment! I think in the example given by joriki in his answer, $X_n\to_{p}1, EX_n=1/2 \forall n,$ so $X_n/EX_n \to 1/2 \ne 1.$ Isn't this another proof, since limit in probability must be almost surely unique?

Comment: @Learning Math That's right. In joriki's example, no matter the $\epsilon>0$, $\mathrm{P}(|X_n-1|\geqslant\epsilon)=\mathrm{P}(X_n=n+1)=n^{-1}\to0$. So $X_n$ converges to one in probability, and you can combine that with your knowledge of the expectation to deduce the probability limit of their ratio. I had the less ambitious goal in mind of showing that the ratio did *not* converge to one in probability.